# Weird if/else behavior Android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm trying to cacth done action which comes from softkeyboard. My code is like this;

```
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener getDoneListener() {
    return new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                nextPage();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

However even though IDE evaluates "(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)"as true, it's not calling nextPage(), returning false instead. If I cast expression like this, it works fine.

```
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener getDoneListener() {
    return new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((boolean)(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                processPayment();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE returns an int i do believe thats why you need to cast it

Comment: @brad [Yep](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE). So it's an int == int comparison which should be alright. I'm a bit baffled by this.

Comment: is it memory issue == -> is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location would  .equals() fix it? I dont do much java programming at new place so its been a bit

Comment: Could you try `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId` as well?  Also, maybe try deleting the whole `if` condition and typing it in fresh?  Otherwise, this has me stumped.